# angular-cli change port to 3000 in angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, port, angular-cli

i use the material todo app from Daniel Zen and want to change to port in the angular-cli.json.
https://github.com/danielzen/material-todo

But this doesn't work.
I tried this:

```
{
  "port" : 3000,
```

But nothing happens.
Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Edit with Angular-CLI 1.0.0**

You can now directly define the used port in the `.angular-cli.json` file by defining the property like this:

```
{
    "defaults": {
        "serve": {
            "port": 2500
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a direct link to all available options for the configuration: [Angular-CLI options configuration](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli)

**Old Answer**

You can configure it directly in your `packages.json`, change your `start` scripts by:

```
"start": "ng serve --port 2500",
```

And then run your server with `npm start`

Comment: for access from other pcs in the same network use this: "start": "ng serve --port 3000 --host x.x.x.x" and change x to server ip

Comment: But he wants to set it in `.angular-cli.json`. How would he do that?

Comment: Take note, that the schema has changed and placing a `port` value in the root under `serve` will cause an error. It needs to be nested under `options` as in the other answer provided

Answer (score 15):

As in new version .angular-cli.json is not visible. You can set `port` in `serve` section of `angular.json` like this:

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "formation:build",
            "port": 5001
          },
 ....
```

You can add any port number instead of `5001`

Thats how you can set your `host` aswell, just like port:

```
"host": "your_host_name"
```

Comment: This should be the correct way while using in Prod instead using cli commands

Answer (score 2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2sDQ.png)This worked for me through the command line

**ng serve --open --port 3000**

I have checked with .angular-cli.json, but I am unable to find the same there.[The typed command is highlighted in the image where the terminal is opened and in the second image the appication is ruuning on the port number 3000 which highlighted too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJqcA.png)